# Problemas para usar el FilteredSelectMultiple de Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Soy algo nuevo con Django, y tengo el problema de que cuando utilizo `FilteredSelectMultiple` de Django en mis propias vistas, no se muestra como cuando se asignan los permiso en el admin de Django, sino mas bien esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Permission.objects.all(),
                                            required=True,
                                            widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Permissions", is_stacked=False))
class Media:
    css = {'all': ('/static/admin/css/widgets.css',), }
    js = ('/admin/jsi18n/',)

class Meta:
    model = Group
    fields = '__all__'
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class GrupoRegistrar (LoginYSuperStaffMixin, ValidarPermisosMixin, CreateView):
model = Group
form_class = GroupForm
template_name = "Grupos/registrar_grupos.html"
permission_required = ('', )
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = self.form_class(data= request.POST, files= request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            mensaje = f'{self.model.__name__} registrado correctamente'
            error = 'No existen errores'
            response = JsonResponse({'mensaje': mensaje, 'error': error})
            response.status_code = 201
            return response
        else:
            mensaje = f'{self.model.__name__} no se ha podido registrar!'
            error = form.errors
            response = JsonResponse({'mensaje': mensaje, 'error': error})
            response.status_code = 400
            return response
    return redirect ('empleado:grupos_inicio')
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title">Registro de Grupos de permisos</h2>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    {{ form.media }}

    <form id="form_creacion" action="{% url 'empleado:grupo_registro' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="errores">

            </div>
            {{form}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="cerrarModalCrear();">Cancelar</button>
            <button id="boton_creacion" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="registrarGrupo(
                '{{perms.Empleados.change_empleado}}',
                '{{perms.Empleados.add_usuario}}',
                '{{perms.Empleados.delete_empleado}}');">Confirmar</button>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Necesito que se muestre con el widget que tiene Django para que sea mas fácil el uso de la aplicación.

Estoy utilizando Django 3, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, por favor.

Comment: Te adjunto esta [**guia completa**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820652/need-guidance-with-filteredselectmultiple-widget) sobre el widget [`FilteredSelectMultiple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820652/need-guidance-with-filteredselectmultiple-widget), por otra parte, creo que el problema es el CSS, intenta remplazar la key `all` del atributo `css` de la clase `Meta`: `'all': (os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, '/static/admin/css/widgets.css'),),` , evidentemente importa la configuración ( `from django.conf import settings`) y la librería `os` (`import os`).